# Fastest way to remove N random objects

Tags: python-2.7, performance, random

My question is as follows, I am currently working with a generated list of length m. However the list is supposed to be the result of an algorithm taking n as an argument for the final length. m is always much large than n. Currently I am running a while loop where m is the result of len(list).
ie:

```
from numpy import random as rnd
m = 400000
n = 3000
list = range(0, m)
while len(list) > n:
    rmi = rnd.randint(0, len(list))
    del list[rmi]
    print('%s/%s' %(len(list), n))
```

This approach certainly works but takes an incredibly long time to run. Is there a more efficient and less time consuming way of removing m-n random entries from my list? The entries removed must be random or the resulting list will no longer represent what it should be.

edit:
Later in my code I then have two arrays of size n, which need to be shortened to size b, the caveat here being that both lists need to have the elements removed randomly but the elements removed must also share the same index. ie:

```
from numpy import random as rnd
n = 3000
b = 500
list1 = range(0, n)
list2 = rnd.sample(xrange(10000), n)
while len(list1) > b:
    rmi = rnd.randint(0, len(list1))
    del list1[rmi]
    del list2[rmi]
    print('%s/%s' %(len(list1), b)
```

alvis' answer below answers the first part of my question however it does not work for the second part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try numpy.random.choice, it creates random sample of your list:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

```
import numpy as np
...
np.random.choice(range(0,m), size=n)
```

Comment: Thank you this solved a part of my problem however now later in my code I run into the issue where I need to remove the same indexed element randomly from two separate arrays, one representing time and the other simulated value.

Comment: You can run this on range(m) and interpret result as a sample index, after extract your actual data by selection by this index: `list_sample = list[np.random.choice(range(m),size=n)]`. So, you can do `list_2_sample = list_2[ind]` if `ind` is the result of choise